# Conditional Formatting for a cell containing a particular equation

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I tried using steps identified [here](http://www.j-walk.com/ss/excel/usertips/tip045.htm) but realized that it refers to cells that have any formula in them. I would like to format based on one particular formula.

Is it possible to use conditional formatting to refer to a cell that only has a particular equation, for example an "IF" statement in the cell?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what the formula is but do mention an IF statement so suggest (though clearly not Conditional Formatting in the conventional sense), HOME, Editing - Find & Select, Find what:

```
=*IF(*
```

<kbd>Find All</kbd>, Ctrl+A, and formatting of your choice.